# Microsoft asp.net core MVC tutorial: error with decimals

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-core

Following this tutorial
https://docs.asp.net/en/dev/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html
I got the problem: "You may not be able to enter decimal points or commas in the Price field" (see note in the page)

I will check globalization section as they suggest, but now I would like to understand why I don't get an error; if I try to insert a decimal number with "." as decimal separator, the insert or edit page just reloads showing no errors.

Please, could you help me?

Comment: A `.` for the decimal separator is valid for client side validation and if you server culture also accepts `.`, then there will be no validation error

Comment: Thanks for replay, I'd like to use "," or "."
I modified js validation, but if I use "." the page reloads without saving

Comment: If you debugged your `MoviesController`, does it get hit by application?

Comment: Debugging I can see in ModelState: Price = 3,55 caught as invalid.
So ModelState.IsValid = False.  

In the binding 
 Create([Bind("ID,Genre,Price,ReleaseDate,Title")] Movie movie)
Price is binded with 0 cause 3,55 is not valid